# Outer Circle Progress Bar

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am attempting to have the outer circle of the progress bar align with the dark circle behind it. I have adjusted the height and width of multiple elements but no luck.

I have tried:

- Adjusting width of SVG
- Adjusting height and width of circle

Here is how I am trying to make it look:

[image]

Here is how it currently looks:
[image]

Please help to explain what I should adjust?

```css
#progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 55%;
  transform: translate(-51%, -50%);
  width: 40%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container .card {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container .card:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.percent {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px #000;
  background: #222;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.percent .number {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.percent .number h2 {
  color: #777;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card:hover .percent .number h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.percent .number h2 span {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #777;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card:hover .percent .number h2 span {
  color: #fff;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  color: #777;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

svg {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

svg circle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #191919;
  stroke-width: 10;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  transform: translate(5px, 5px);
}

svg circle:nth-child(2) {
  stroke-dasharray: 440;
  stroke-dashoffset: 440;
}

.card:nth-child(1) svg circle:nth-child(2) {
  stroke-dashoffset: calc(
    440 - (440 * 90) / 100
  ); /* use to adjust progress bar */
  stroke: #00ff43;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="box">
                  <div class="percent">
                    <svg>
                      <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
                      <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
                    </svg>
                    <div class="number">
                      <h2>90<span>%</span></h2>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <h2 class="text">Html</h2>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Noah, however it only centered the outer circle (green circle); I am attempting to scale the outer circle (green circle) to match the size of the inner dark circle (black circle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<style>
    svg {
      position: relative;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      z-index: 1000;
    }
    svg circle{
        fill: none;
        stroke-width: 10;
        stroke-linecap: round;
        stroke-dasharray: 1000;
    }
    svg circle:nth-child(2){
        stroke: #f00;
        stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
        animation: dash 2s linear forwards;
    }
    svg circle:nth-child(1){
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        stroke: #000;
    }
    @keyframes dash {
      to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }
</style>
<body>
<svg>
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="40%"></circle>
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="40%"></circle>
</svg>
</body>
```

set the values `cx` and `cy` to `50%` and `r` to `40%`
the simple animation above should shows the animation `stroke-dashoffset` between `stroke-dashoffset: 0;` and `stroke-dashoffset: 1000;` 
It should be mentioned that the value between 0 and 1000 is not linear. That means `stroke-dashoffset: 100;` is not 10% of the circle. 
You can implement this sample to your code and resize the svg width and height in %.